# Dragging elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im just wondering whether its possible to drag images/elements (whether inside a div or not) where the image/element is dragged to the far left and comes in from the right side of the screen - therefore dragging the image/element left to get the same result, or vice versa.

Similar to the google maps (on zoom level 1) the user can continuously drag the image left or right, and those images are on a continuous loop.

If so, what languages would you recommend using? javascript?

I hope this makes sense.

Many thanks

Comment: javascript could do it with the help of css and html

Comment: Take a look at this http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: You can use mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events to keep track of what is being dragged. It will be harder to handle the wrap around. I would start by creating a clone of the image element, making sure the container is set to overflow:hidden, and using javascript to position the clone at (normal img x-pos + container width) pixels

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible using Javascript. Just have two copies of the image, and as you slide the images left, move the second copy to the right side. (Or vice versa if sliding right).

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handlers to any element, including your images, that execute code while dragging. I apologize for not providing a complete working solution, I am pressed for time, I hope this helps as a starting point

```
var myGlobals = {
  state: {
    dragging: false;
  }
};

$('.carouselImg').on('mousedown', function(e){
  myGlobals.state.dragging = true;
});

$(window).on('mouseup', function(e){
  // stop movement even if mouseup happens somewhere outside the carousel
  myGlobals.state.dragging = false; 
});

$(window).on('mousemove', function(e){
  // allow user to drag beyond confines of the carousel
  if(myGlobals.state.dragging == true){
    recalculateCarouselPosition(e);
  }
});

function recalculateCarouselPosition(e){
  // These fun bits are left as an exercise for the reader
  // the event variable `e` gives you the pixel coordinates where the mouse is
  // You will have to do some math to determine what you need to do after this drag.
  // You may want to store the coordinates of the initial click in 
  // `myGlobals.dragStart.x, .y` or similar so you can easily compare them
  // You will probably set a negative CSS margin-left property on some element
  // of your carousel.
  // The carousel will probably have overflow:hidden.
  // You will also have to manipulate the DOM, by adding a duplicate image to the
  // opposite end and deleting the duplicates once they have scrolled out of view

};
```